# Group within table angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table

I'm relatively new to Angular but using it to build out a dynamic pivot table structure.

Here's basically what the end result is supposed to look like (sorry for poor image quality):

[image: pivot table]

both the number of aggregates and the number of grouping values are dynamic.

the problem arises when I try to print out the second row in the table. I need to print a  cell for each aggregate function (SUM and AVG in the example, but could be more or fewer) and then repeat THAT for each of the horizontal grouping values.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
directives.directive('pivotTableHeader', function() {
return {
    template: '<thead><tr><th>{{horizontalGroupProperty}}</th>\
    <th ng-repeat="horizontalGroup in horizontalGroupValues" colspan="aggregates.length">{{horizontalGroup}}</th></tr>\
    <tr><th>{{verticalGroupProperty}}</th>\
    <pivot-table-agg-cols ng-repeat="horizontalGroup in horizontalGroupValues"></pivot-table-agg-cols>\
    </tr></thead>'
    };
```

});

inside the pivot-table-agg-cols:

```
directives.directive('pivotTableAggCols', function(){
    return {
        template:'<th ng-repeat="column in aggregates">{{column.display}}</th>'
    };  
})
```

the problem is that the browser won't tolerate the *pivot-table-agg-cols* tag, it's like the directive doesn't even exist (never initialized). And because it's a table I can't just wrap in a `<div>` like I would elsewhere. Any tips on how I can handle this? Is there a way to inject a directive template without also adding a parent element?

Comment: Why don't you just inline the template of the pivotTableAggCols directly inside the template of pivotTableHeader? I don't see what you gain in making it a separate directive.

Comment: How would the outer ng-repeat work in that case?

Comment: Ah, I see now. You could add a field or method in horizontalGroup that contains/returns all the columns of all the horizontal groups.